# MVC form send value to remote verifier

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to use a remote verifier for user email existence against my database, my problem is it's posting my email under a name i don't know how to get on the `Action` as a parameter.

This is my attribute:

```
[Remote( "EmailExists", "Register", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Email already exists!" )]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

This is my Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult EmailExists( string email )
{
    using (var db = new SOSEntities())
    {
        var user = db.VT_Usuario.FirstOrDefault( us => us.email.Equals( email ) );

        return Json( user == null );
    }
}
```

and this is how the email is being posted to the action, i got this info on the headers of the post (Form Data):

```
user.Email: ariel%40teste.com
```

My user class is inside a `ViewModel` with some other models that i use on the project, the user data is inside a `user` object inside the `ViewModel`, and by that the data is posted as `user.Email`.

What can i do to work around this ?

Comment: Did you try adding the user model as the param? `public JsonResult EmailExists( User user )` and then just use `us.email.Equals( user.Email )`

Comment: @JamieD77, exactly what i needed, Shyju answer also worked but with your answer it's possible to maintain my actual ViewModel. If you want to post an answer i will accept it

Comment: Because its a property of a complex object, you can also use the `Prefix` property of the `[Bind]` attribute - `public JsonResult EmailExists[Bind(Prefix = "user.Email")]string Email)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be using a flattened view model which has properties needed for the view. Only those properties, nothing else. And in your Action method, you read the property values of the posted viewmodel and map it to other entities as needed ( in a Mapping layer or Business layer as needed).

so your viewmodel will be something like

```
public class CreateCustomer
{
  public string Name {set;get;}
  public string Email{set;get;}    
}
```

Comment: The problem with that is my code is messy right now, i had to mix my validation attributes with my other models that don't use it to make it work like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an AJAX call to the method and use the results.

```
 $.ajax({

            url: 'http://MySite/myController/EmailExists',
            data: '{email:"dog@bark.com"}',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (result) { document.write(JSON.stringify(result)) }
})
```

Comment: Wouldn't work since i'm using mvc validation on the form so i would only provide a warning and not really validate the form